# Embed attributes in Name or Description

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, attributes

I'm trying to work out a way of embedding attributes in other attributes, e.g. name or description in Magento 2.3

As an example

static product name - Blue T-Shirt Size Large

dynamic - {colour_attribute} T-Shirt Size {size_attribute}

{colour_attribute} and {size_attribute} would be separate M2 attributes

I'm not sure it's possible and I can't find a module to do it and I wondered if anyone has tried this?

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Do you want to implement this for all products?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
No, I need to able to do it on some products and not others.